# What is this light grey LEGO plate with six sides (hexagon)?

Tags: part-identification

[image: Lego Piece]

I've been unable to find this specific piece's name, just for the reason that it is a very unorthodox piece.

Answer (score 57):

Informally, it's known as the Nexogon.

[image: Part image]

Bricklink calls it "Plate, Modified 6 x 6 Hexagonal with Pin Hole". The part number is [27255](https://rebrickable.com/parts/27255/). It's original use was as a shield in the Nexo Knights line in 2017, but it has appeared in a few other sets since then.

[image: Clay]

If you're interested in ways to use this part, New Elementary did a [whole series of posts](http://www.newelementary.com/search?q=nexogon) from different builders when it was first released. The unique shape and different connection families open up a lot of fun opportunities.

[image: icosahedron]

[image: hive]

[image: office building]

[image: NCS vehicle]

[image: underwater]

Comment: So beautiful, that is

Comment: Is there any name for that type of irregular hexagon? I couldn't find any in MathWorld. Also, here's more fan stuff on Nexogon:https://www.brothers-brick.com/2017/01/19/new-nexo-knights-nexogon-part-analysis-new-elementary-guest-post/

Comment: From their [image](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-xoMZvHfvR-w/WHePThK2qxI/AAAAAAAAGac/yZk7jsLaPt8n-UkKbbT7MEX3F6HDQs_vQCEw/s640/make-hexagon-connect-six-nexo-kinghts-shield-triangular-plate-27255.jpg), the long:short sidelengths have ratio 2:1

Comment: @smci: You can see this hexagon as a [truncated equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_(geometry)#Truncation_of_polygons).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been having such a hard time trying to identify this piece, but you made my job so much easier. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

This is what I managed to create with the Nexogons:

[image: Archimedean bodies]

Flickr Album: https://www.flickr.com/photos/162108633@N02/albums/72157688876724660